# Yellow cards that change the trading rules: how many coins should I pay?

Tags: 7-wonders-duel

If you have a yellow card that gives you the right to buy something for one coin, do the opponent's resources still take effect?

For example if my opponent has two stone and I have the card that changes the trading rules for stone, if I need to buy one extra stone would I pay **one coin** or **3 coins** (one coin plus one coin for every resource my opponent has)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regardless of the number of resource producing buildings your opponent has, you always get to buy the given resource for 1 coin

Quote from the official rules:

> Some commercial Buildings (yellow cards) change the trading rules and
>   set the cost of some resources to 1 coin.